# c# calculation parser

Tags: c#, string, parsing

Say I have a string like `"(12.2*(5/7))"`, is there an API/method that can parse this or would I need to write one from scratch?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are such frameworks. Just google for '.NET expression parser' and you get plenty of results!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write one or find a library to do this. There is nothing built into .NET to support this as standard.

One thing I've found myself considering when looking at problems like this is an Excel library (we already use one called [FlexCel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp)) which will handle all the standard Excel syntax and provide a rich suite of functions. You just end up excluding the excel specific ranges. The nice thing about this, is almost everyone knows how to use Excel functions already.

Answer (score 0):

See the CodeProject.com article [Implementing Programming Language Tools in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/programminglanguagetoools.aspx). Included samples include an arithmetic evaluator and a JavaScript to expression tree compiler. Combining these should provide you with what you want.